# Realm Query case insensitive

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I want search with case insensitive when use Realm.

I have an object Area (Realm object) with 2 fields: areaID (NSString, primary key) and areaName (NSString).

I use NSPredicate to search:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"areaName == [c] %@", areaName]

In my database, has a record has areaName = "TP. Hồ Chí Minh"
when I query with "TP. HỒ CHÍ MINH", the results is empty,
and I query with "tp. hồ chí minh", the results has 1 record.

So, I wanna ask why the fisrt query returns an empty result.

Comment: how you done this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like this is actually a diacritic-insensitive search, rather than merely a case-insensitive one. Realm supports case-insensitive queries, but does not yet have full support for localized text search.

Comment: then how can we do this?